# Not able to connect with mfp server 7.1 version + ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

I am developing my ionic app.I have to integrate it with mobile first 7.1 version.So i have done the following steps,

1) **Cordova app creation:**

```
mfp cordova create appname
```

**2) ionic app creation:**

```
 ionic start appname blank
```

Then, i has copied my **ionic app www folder** & pasted it in my **cordova** project.While trying to run my app **"I am not able connect with server"**.Getting failed in the bellow code,

```
 WL.Client.connect({
      onSuccess :function(){ alert("success")},
      onFailure :function(){ alert("Fail")},
  });
```

I am using my routed URL only in my config.xml page. That url i have checked in both my browser as well as in my device also. but still i am not able to connect with the server.

Everyone help will be Appreciated !!!!

Comment: Provide your failing application.

Comment: You get my sample app by using the following link,
  https://github.com/Smohanapriya/mfp-7.1-with-ionic

Answer (score 0):

Did you make sure to also run the command "mfp push" from the application's root folder so that it would be registered in the MobileFirst Server? Otherwise, your application will fail connecting.

Also, instead of printing "fail", print the response.errorMsg to find out a possible cause for the failure:

```
onFailure :function(response){ alert(response.errorMsg)},
```

Comment: I getting error response as   "status" : 500 only
I have push my application to mfp & i can able to view appliction name  over there.

Comment: I don't understand what you're writing. Paste here the error message.